# EWS/Exchange.asmx return error code 401 on MacOS

Tags: windows, macos, outlook, exchangewebservices

[401 UnAuthorized Access when using EWS to connect to mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346498/401-unauthorized-access-when-using-ews-to-connect-to-mailbox)

Here is my problem but without any solution!
EWS works on Windows, but when I run it on my MacOS - 401 unauthorized!

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:
I have added https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard nuget and then
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gss-ntlmssp into Dockerfile(for Ubuntu, maybe needs for Debian).
Also for Linux need to set UseDefaultCredentials = false for ExchangeService.

Comment: Hi, 
I had the same problem, then I solved thanks to you but with different setup.

Comment: sudo yum makecache sudo yum -y install gssntlmssp - Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices  nuget