# Getting EWS folders with Web Api Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, exchangewebservices

Getting 401 (Unauthorized) error in IIS while trying to bind to the EWS folder in Web Api Core (locally works fine). The minimal code below.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Url = new Uri(ewsUrl)
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
Folder rootFolder = await Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
```

IIS settings:

- Anonymous = false
- Impersonation = false (true gives the error 500)
- Windows Authentication = true
- Other settings = false

.Net Core seems to be does not support in-code impersonation, so I tried above code in .NET Framework, inclosed it in this statement. Unfortunately, the same 401 error.

```
IIdentity WinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
WindowsImpersonationContext wic = wi.Impersonate();
try
{
...
}
catch (Exception ex1)
{ }
finally
{
wic.Undo();
}
```

Appreciate for help!

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43358743/7687666)

Comment: Jason, unfortunately not. I guess I have to deal with server-side delegation, but not with delegation for specific mailboxes, but with delegation for any calling account. Not sure how to achieve that. Though, I was able to impersonate users by modifying application pool settings. Still getting the error.